# Can Hive support Primary keys functionality

Tags: hive, cloudera, impala, hue

I am on hive 1.2 version.
We have a requirement where we would like to store data in HIve tables 3-4 times a day and the tables should have primary keys capability so that the delta's are taken care of and we can avoid duplicate records.

Has anyone face similar situation and have any workarounds, as i am finding hive doesnot support primary keys functionality until 2.1 version.

Thank you

Comment: have you considered using kudu? Kudu tables supports unique primary key

Comment: Thank you Luk, Can we send data from Hive to Kudu to process this so data is stored correctly ? Or the update be made directly at Kudu level ? thanks

Comment: Hi @user10591810, Did you got solution? Please let us know